# Highlight a text on PDF & save the highlighted document

Tags: android

I want to highlight a text on PDF & save the document containing the highlighted text.

Is it technically feasible with existing Android API (till OS ver 3.0)?

Kindly provide your suggestions regarding the feasibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "existing API" for displaying PDF files. You would need to find a third-party PDF reader application and determine if it has the feature you seek.